# How to add onClick event in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am having trouble with adding a onClick event within JavaScript variable. Not sure how the syntax should be written. Thanks for any help.

```
var jumpTo = 'https://google.com/ onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link', 'Clicked',]);"'
```

Comment: What element are you trying to add the event to?

Comment: A variable doesn't have an onclick event.  What is going to be clicked on?  Currently your one line of code doesn't make a lot of sense, and isn't even valid code (it has syntax errors in the string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you're trying to achive:

html:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="btn_click()" />
```

javascript:

```
function btn_click() {
    var url = 'https://google.com';
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', url, 'Clicked']);
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to escape the single quotes

```
var jumpTo = 'https://google.com/ onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'link\', \'Clicked\']);"'
```

lg

fastrde

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help and to those who responded.